# Collection of all finite sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is the collection of all finite sets a set or a proper class? If it's a set how to prove otherwise alos how to prove? And finite set means sets which are in 1-to-1 correspondence with $\{1,2,3,...,n\}$ where $n$ is a natural number.

Comment: @frabala It is a class not a set, and certainly isn't countable.

Comment: I'm sorry. I deleted it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Let $U$ denote the universe of all sets.

If $F=\left\{ a\mid a\text{ finite}\right\} $
is indeed a set then $S=\left\{ \left\{ x\right\} \mid x\in U\right\} $
is a subset of $F$ (see hint of Clive). Then $\bigcup S$ is also a set. However $\bigcup S=U$.

A contradiction.

Comment: What is $\cup S$? There is only one $S$ here right?

Comment: @dezign Yes, there is only one $S$. In set-theory (where all objects are sets) there is the axiom of union. It states that for every set $a$ there is a set $b$ such that $x\in b$ iff $x$ is element of some element of $a$ (so some set $c$ exists with $x\in c\in a$. This set $b$ is denoted as $\bigcup a$. Note that e.g. $\bigcup\{A,B\}=A\cup B$ and $\bigcup\{A_i|i\in I\}=\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i$.

Comment: Ok that clears things up!

Answer (score 18):

**Hint:** If $x$ is a set then $\{ x \}$ is a finite set.