# Why is a groupoid required to be a small category?

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, groupoids

I'm learning category theory and every definition of a groupoid has required that a groupoid be a small category (or some equivalent requirement) but I don't really know why.

So what is the reason that a groupoid is required to be a small category and what would happen if that requirement were dropped?

A reference would be great if at all possible.

Thanks.

Comment: I'd imagine it's because the authors want to talk about the category of groupoids. But that's just a guess, honestly

Comment: @SheafKeef That was my guess by I couldn't find anything to back it up or any justification for that specific requirement.

Comment: If the requirement of smallness were dropped then you'd have large groupoids. There's nothing in particular that's wrong with that, except you run into more issues of size. It would be akin to taking the definition of a group to be a class equipped with a binary (class) operation, rather than a set equipped with a binary set operation. (In fact, this is exactly what a group would be, if you took your definition of a group to be a one-object groupoid.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that almost all groupoids which are encountered **in practice** are small (or at least essentially small). You can find a collection [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/groupoid). They come from various branches of mathematics.

Of course, for every category we may consider its [core](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/core), which is a groupoid, which may be large. But when *in practice* does one consider, for example, the category of all sets with bijections as morphisms?

It is also worthwhile mentioning that Brandt, who invented groupoids, assumed them to be small. Groupoids were conceived as multi-object versions of groups, or as groups with partially defined operations. Although there are, of course, large groups in nature (for instance, the surreal numbers form a large field), most groups in practice are small.

Comment: It's is actually quite common to consider the groupoid of *finite* sets and bijections (e.g. to define operads). [And that isn't a small groupoid.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/896270/collection-of-all-finite-sets)

Comment: Yes, sure. This groupoid plays an important  role in several places. It is *essentially small*. It is also often replaced by a small skeleton (finite sets of the form $\{1,\dotsc,n\}$).